# Crystal Reports X CurrentDate in empty field

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to create a Crystal Report that will show the Average days to pay for a customer. But if the customer hasn't paid, then i want the report to assume that the customer paid today.  The trouble i am having is my data returns the unpaid stuff as blank. how and where can i put a formula that will put the Current Date (Date report is run) in the empty Date field?

Answer (score 0):

When Unpaid stuff is blank then display current date using the If formula